# How to download the images displayed through the vuetify v-image component directly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vimage

the native img element  can right-click to open the menu to save the picture,but the vuetify v-image component can't save the picture with right click

it's there have some solutions to help me fix this question, Thank you very much

Comment: This appears to be a feature request for an open source package, which is *off-topic* on [SO]. Consider reaching out directly to the authors of the package, by opening a new issue on [its repo](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify). Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Checked some props of the components + checked the Github issues?

Comment: It is already implemented in Vuetify 3.0.0 and unfortunately will not be backported to 2.X.X, as core contributor said. See [issue 14138](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14138) and [issue 14262](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14262) at Vuetify GitHub repo